# Create a row every time another row is created in django

Tags: python, database, django, model

I want to create a row in one of my databases' tables every time a row in a particular table is created. 
For example:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name               = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug               = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    about              = models.TextField(blank = True, null=True)
```

every time a new row in this table is created, I want to add a new row in a Link class

```
class Link(models.Model):
    name               = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug               = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    location           = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
```

Where the group's slug will be the a part of the Link's location.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal comes in. You could add this to the bottom of your models.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def create_group_links(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Link.objects.create(name='FOO', slug='BAR', location='LOC' + instance.slug)
post_save.connect(create_group_links, sender=Group)
```